# Failed to load resource with Ionic in build Android

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

When I use the `ionic serve` command, I have no problem.

When I use the command `ionic cordova run android --livereload --consolelogs`, sometimes I have no problem, sometimes I have a blank page.

When I do a build on android I have a blank page all the time that appears, I've been looking for a solution for several days.

What i have already tried :

- Uninstall and install android platform
- Uninstall and install ionic and cordova
- Add *cordova-plugin-whitelist* plugin - `ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist`
- Clear cookies/cache
- `npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev`

Here are different errors that appear randomly
[image]
[image]

I have no errors during the build.

Comment: have you tried ionic cordova prepare android? and then build

Comment: yes I already have that too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following meta seems to have solved the problem in config.xml :

```
<access launch-external="yes" origin="tel:*" />
<preference name="LoadUrlTimeoutValue" value="20000" />
```